# Flow error with react render method

Tags: reactjs, flowtype, static-typing

I ran into the error below while trying to add some flow type checking to one of my test apps.

I don't really understand what it means nor how to fix it.

```
render(): ?React.Element {
```

error:

```
Element: 
Application of polymorphic type needs <list of 1 argument>. (Can use `*` for inferrable ones)
```

Let me know if you need more code (maybe class definition etc).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It seems now we should to write `Element<any>` insted just `Element`

Comment: [Flow Docs](https://flowtype.org/docs/functions.html#polymorphic-functions) and https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/ac5636dd59f97a7381acd548e701e83fadcba408/Libraries/Components/StaticRenderer.js#L26

Comment: I wonder why React is using `<any>` instead of `<Object>`.  My understanding of Flow's doc suggests this would be better: https://flow.org/en/docs/types/any/